# how to convert date and time to date

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

i have this string "1/20/2015 12:00:00 AM" and i need to convert in something like this  "20/1/2015" without time and days first.

`DateTime mydate = Convert.ToDateTime(myDateFromDB);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert date string of format "dd/MM/yyyy" to DateTime, should used DateTime.TryParseExact where you can specify the date format string to let the converter know about the Culture.

To get the Date alone, use myDateTimeObj.Date.